# Building C# .NET in command line gives error: Package 'Code Analysis Package' failed to load

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am compile a sample C# .NET project using build.cmd file. The content of the build.cmd is as bellow.

**build.cmd**

```
@echo off
setlocal

set devenv="c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com"

del *.log >nul

%devenv% WindowsFormsApplication3.sln /rebuild "Release" /out WindowsFormsApplication3.log
if ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO failed
findstr /C:"========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========" WindowsFormsApplication3.log >nul
if ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO failed

echo *** BUILD SUCCESSFUL ***
pause
goto :EOF

:failed
echo.
echo.
echo *** BUILD FAILED ***

pause
```

Project compiles properly. But when i opened the log file it hassome error

**WindowsFormsApplication3.log**

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: WindowsFormsApplication3, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------

Package 'Code Analysis Package' failed to load.
1>  WindowsFormsApplication3 -> E:\Bin\junk\WindowsFormsApplication3\WindowsFormsApplication3\bin\Release\WindowsFormsApplication3.exe
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I don't why i am getting this error (Package 'Code Analysis Package' failed to load) in log file.

I searched online but did not get any help.

how to solve this problem?

**Note:** WindowsFormsApplication3 is a sample project. i Opened VS2015 and New Project -> Visual C# -> Windows Form Application. I did not change any thing in the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give Microsoft a chance to analyze and fix the problem.
I created a connect issue because the problem occurs on two PCs that both have vanilla VS 2015 installations.
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2423616/package-code-analysis-package-failed-to-load
Within the next few weeks, a guy from Microsoft will probably comment on that. You can followup there.